# How to add arbitrary values, not present in the database, to selected rows in MySQL SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

---

Dear SQL Experts,

I want to select a very large result set from a public `MySQL` database and subsequently avoid long running post-processing of the results in memory.

Please, regard the following example:

**QUERY**

```
SELECT id, name, nationality 
FROM user 
WHERE nationality 
IN ('British','German','Korean');
```

I get approximately 500k rows and want to extend them with an arbitrary column, such that the resulting table has a fourth row `favorite_food` which is `Hamburger` for `British`, `Soup` for `Korean`, and `Sauerkraut` for `German` users.

In fact in my real live problem I'd like to add two such "arbitrary" columns with values non existing in the database and depending on the values supplied to the `WHERE` clause.

Allow me to remark, that I do not have any writing rights on the database, so I cannot change existing tables or contained data in any way.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: I have no idea about MySQL, but since it tends to be the same as T-SQL, there you'd do just a `SELECT (CASE nationality WHEN 'British' THEN 'Hamburger' WHEN 'Korean' THEN 'Soup'...ELSE 'Unknown') END FROM user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT id,name,nationality,(
CASE nationality 
WHEN 'British' THEN 'Hamburger' 
WHEN 'German' THEN 'Sauerkraut' 
WHEN 'Korean' THEN 'Soup' 
ELSE NULL END) AS 'favorite_food'
FROM user
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5fda/10)**

Comment: Thank you very much Ullas. Maybe you can even help me solve the [next question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849900/how-to-extend-a-sql-result-set-with-arbitrary-columns-and-rows)?

Comment: If this solved your issue, please mark it as answer.