# How to extend a SQL result set with arbitrary columns and rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

Please, allow me to explain my problem in a somewhat lengthy way.

I have an in-memory association of **proteins**, their **functions** and the **evidence codes**, that informs about how we now, that a certain protein has the stated function.

**Example**

```
| Protein | Evidence Code | GO-Term    |
+---------+---------------+------------+
| prot_1  | 'EXP'         | GO:0030599 |
| prot_2  | 'IEA'         | GO:0030599 |
```

Please note that the functions are encoded as [Gene Ontology (GO) Terms](http://geneontology.org/). This is a database of *hierarchically* arranged protein function descriptions, where with increasing depth a given function description (GO term) is a more detailed - or precise - description than its ancestor. In fact the GO terms are arranged in a **hierarchical acyclic graph (GO DAG)**.

The above GO term `GO:0030599` has several such ancestors. See `Inferred Tree View` [here](http://amigo.geneontology.org/amigo/term/GO:0030599). The term's ancestors can be obtained from a public `MySQL` database

```
mysql -h mysql.ebi.ac.uk -u go_select -P 4085 -pamigo go_latest
```

using the following, rather long

**Query**

```
SELECT t.*, to_root.relation_distance, child.acc as child_acc
  FROM graph_path res LEFT JOIN term t ON t.id = res.term1_id
  LEFT JOIN graph_path to_root ON t.id = to_root.term2_id
  LEFT JOIN term child ON child.id = res.term2_id
  WHERE
  res.term1_id != (SELECT r.id FROM term r WHERE r.is_root = 1)
  AND child.acc in ('GO:0030599')
  AND to_root.term1_id =
  (SELECT r.id FROM term r WHERE r.is_root = 1)
  GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY to_root.relation_distance ASC
```

I can extend it, unfortunately so far **only** *for a single protein*, such that I get something like the **desired result**, which is the in-memory association merged with the result set:

**Query**

```
SELECT t.*, to_root.relation_distance, child.acc as child_acc,
  (CASE child.acc
    WHEN 'GO:0030599' THEN 'Prot_1'
    ELSE NULL END) as 'prot'
  FROM graph_path res LEFT JOIN term t ON t.id = res.term1_id
  LEFT JOIN graph_path to_root ON t.id = to_root.term2_id
  LEFT JOIN term child ON child.id = res.term2_id
  WHERE
  res.term1_id != (SELECT r.id FROM term r WHERE r.is_root = 1)
  AND child.acc in ('GO:0030599')
  AND to_root.term1_id =
  (SELECT r.id FROM term r WHERE r.is_root = 1)
  GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY to_root.relation_distance ASC
```

**Desired example result**

```
| Protein | Evidence Code | GO-Term                    |
+---------+---------------+----------------------------+
| prot_1  | 'EXP'         | GO:0030599 itself          |
| prot_1  | 'EXP'         | GO:0030599 first ancestor  |
| prot_1  | 'EXP'         | GO:0030599 second ancestor |
| prot_1  | 'EXP'         | GO:0030599 third ancestor  |
```

**My question is:**

How to modify the above `SQL` query such that it copies the above example result rows but for protein `prot_2`, too:

```
| Protein | Evidence Code | GO-Term                    |
+---------+---------------+----------------------------+
| prot_1  | 'EXP'         | GO:0030599 itself          |
| prot_1  | 'EXP'         | GO:0030599 first ancestor  |
| prot_1  | 'EXP'         | GO:0030599 second ancestor |
| prot_1  | 'EXP'         | GO:0030599 third ancestor  |
| prot_2  | 'IEA'         | GO:0030599 itself          |
| prot_2  | 'IEA'         | GO:0030599 first ancestor  |
| prot_2  | 'IEA'         | GO:0030599 second ancestor |
| prot_2  | 'IEA'         | GO:0030599 third ancestor  |
```

I hope this **edit** of my question is much clearer than the original version.

Help will be much appreciated.
Thank you very much!

Comment: How is your `person` table structure??

Comment: Dear Ullas, the `person` table has only two columns `name` and `ancestor`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Then how do you wanna get the output?

Comment: I fear I did not manage to explain my question well. I want to generate a `SQL` `SELECT` statement _using_ the in-memory association such that the association data is introduced as arbitrary columns. Just like in your solution for my [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837969/how-to-add-arbitrary-values-not-present-in-the-database-to-selected-rows-in-my).

Comment: @user3139868 . . . Please explain why your query with the `case` doesn't solve point (2).

Comment: Dear Gordon, it actually does. My bad. I tried to give a simple example of my problem. Now I realize that my example is too simple. I will update my question with the real thing, hoping to finally stop confusing the community. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to achieve this with plain old SQL?

No, there isn't. That in-memory association of married couples would have to be known to MySQL. Unless stored in a (temporary) table on MySQL you're going to have to do this processing on the client end where that data is available.

Comment: Well, of course, you are right Leeft. But the in-memory association can be made known to the database using approach like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837969/how-to-add-arbitrary-values-not-present-in-the-database-to-selected-rows-in-my)

Comment: Considering your data takes 3 hours to process, it's highly unlikely you'd be able to fit all the spouse data into a query that will be accepted by MySQL. And then, even if it accepted the query, it might take MySQL itself a significant amount of time to parse it. That's why I haven't even suggested it. That said, maybe your processing approach itself can be optimised, but that's out of the realm of this question.